# iterating over one column of a numpy multidimensional array?

Tags: multidimensional-array, numpy

I have a (2, 500) numpy array named `county_data`. I want to iterate over the first column, check if each value is equal to a number `someNumber`, and if so, attach its row to a list called `temp`.

Here is my code so far:

```
for entry in county_data:       
    if entry[0] == someNumber:  
        temp.append(entry)  
    print temp
```

Here's the error I get:

```
   if entry[0] == code:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I don't quite know what this means, and the `a.any()` and `a.all()` functions don't seem to do what I want with each row in the array. How can I edit my code to check that the first entry in each row of the array matches `someNumber`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do that.  Instead, access all the rows at once (i.e., *vectorize* your code):

```
temp = county_data[county_data[:, 0] == someNumber]
```